# fullCalendar v2 get view start/end moment

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am currently migrating from old version (1.5.4) to new (2.0.2), and I'm expiriencing problems with new momentsJS framework which is integrated to fullCalendar.

I have these lines in y code:

```
url: url,
cache: false,
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
ignoreTimezone:true,
data:
{
    start:  moment( $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView").start ).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    end:    moment( $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView").end ).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
}
```

They indeed working, but throwing the warning in console:

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This
>   is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please
>   refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

As far as I understood `$("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView").start` returns a moment object:

> FCMoment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: undefined, _f: undefined, _l:
>   undefined, _strict: undefined…}

But I can't use format() method on it, because it throws error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'format' of undefined

I have no clue why warning is thrown, and where is a problem, can someone please guide me to  solution?

Comment: Consider reporting this to [fullcalendar's issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues).